# Build a decision Column by ANDing multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which is shown below:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,4,4,3],[2,4,5,6,7]]
>>> columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data = x, columns = columns)
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  4  4  3
2  2  4  5  6  7
```

I have an array of objects (`conditions`) as shown below:

```
[
                                {
                                    'header' : 'a',
                                    'condition' : '==',
                                    'values' : [1]
                                },
                                {
                                    'header' : 'b',
                                    'condition' : '==',
                                    'values' : [2]
                                },
                                ...

                            ]
```

and an `assignHeader` which is:
`assignHeader = decision`

now I want to do an operation which builds up all the conditions from the `conditions` array by looping through it, for example something like this:

```
pConditions = []
            for eachCondition in conditions:
                header = eachCondition['header']
                values = eachCondition['values']
                if eachCondition['condition'] == "==":
                    pConditions.append(df[header].isin(values))
                else:
                    pConditions.append(~df[header].isin(values))
                
            df[assignHeader ] = and(pConditions)
```

I was thinking of using `all` operator in pandas but am unable to crack the right syntax to do so. The list I shared can go big and dynamic and so I want to use this nested approach and check for the equality. Does anyone know a way to do so?

Final Output:

`conditons = [df['a']==1,df['b']==2]`

```
>>> df['decision'] = (df['a']==1) & (df['b']==2)
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  decision
0  1  2  3  4  5      True
1  1  2  4  4  3      True
2  2  4  5  6  7     False
```

Here `conditions` array will be variable. And I want to have a function which takes `df`, 'newheadername`and`conditions` as input and returns the output as shown below:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e  decision
0  1  2  3  4  5      True
1  1  2  4  4  3      True
2  2  4  5  6  7     False
```

where `newheadername` = `'decision'`

Comment: why not try `numpy.select`

Comment: Can you give an example of the same in answers?

Comment: sure; it would help if you shared the expected final output

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I have updated my problems as you said... would love to have your feedback and answer

Comment: i think your solution covers it pretty well

Comment: Hmm yeah thanks, in case you want to share your approach feel free to add it up here. Would love to check that as well... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the code shown below. I am not sure if this is kind of fast way of getting things done, but would love to know your inputs in case you have any specific thing to point out.

```
def andMerging(conditions, mergeHeader, df):
        if len(conditions) != 0:
            df[mergeHeader] = pd.concat(conditions, axis = 1).all(axis = 1)
        return df
```

where conditions are an array of `pd.Series` with boolean values.

And conditions are formatted as shown below:

```
def prepareForConditionMerging(conditionsArray, df):
        conditions = []
        for prop in conditionsArray:
            condition = prop['condition']
            values = prop['values']
            header = prop['header']
            if type(values) == str:
                values = [values]
            
            if condition=="==":
                conditions.append(df[header].isin(values))
            else:
                conditions.append(~df[header].isin(values))
            # Here we can add more conditions such as greater than less than etc.

        return conditions
```